# Magento version 2.3.2 how to change tinymce js path

Tags: magento

Magento version 2.3.2 show hide editor not working inside whole admin. When i try to add/update any product or pages and click on show/hide editor button editor does not show and inside console.log it show 404 not found mysite.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js.

I have tried all related commands but not found where it is calling tinymce.js. In magento 2.3 correct path is static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tiny_mce_4/tinymce.min.js

But i have no idea where i need to change this path. Inside require.js have no clue to find out real path.

Any one can help me.

I have tried all related commands 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: can you check my answer? is it helpful to you?

Comment: here is the right path of tinymce: lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/tinymce4Adapter.js

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed issue by modify in lib/web/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js

1-Find code near line 10833

```
tinymce.documentBaseURL = window.location.href.replace(/[\?#].*$/, '').replace(/[\/\\][^\/]+$/, '');
if (!/[\/\\]$/.test(tinymce.documentBaseURL))
tinymce.documentBaseURL += '/';
```

Replace with

```
tinymce.documentBaseURL = ADMIN_BASE_URL+"/tiny_mce";
tinymce.baseURL = ADMIN_BASE_URL+"/tiny_mce";
if(IS_MINIFY == 1) tinymce.suffix = '.min'; else tinymce.suffix = '';
```

2- Find code near line 11391

```
sl.add(tinymce.baseURL + '/langs/' + s.language + '.js');
```

Replace with

```
sl.add(tinymce.baseURL + '/langs/' + s.language + tinymce.suffix + '.js');
```

3- Find code near line 10758

```
tinymce.ScriptLoader.add(this.urls[n] + '/langs/' + s.language + '.js');
```

Replace with

```
tinymce.ScriptLoader.add(this.urls[n] + '/langs/' + s.language + tinymce.suffix + '.js');
```

Change code in bellow file or override in admin theme:

```
vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml
```

4- Find code:

```
<script>
var BASE_URL = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('*') ?>';
var FORM_KEY = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey() ?>';
var require = {
"baseUrl": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('/') ?>"
};
</script>
```

`
Replace code with:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$scopeConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');
$isMinify = $scopeConfig->getValue('dev/js/minify_files', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
?>
<script>
var BASE_URL = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('*') ?>';
var FORM_KEY = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey() ?>';
var ADMIN_BASE_URL = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('/') ?>';
var IS_MINIFY = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $isMinify ?>';
var require = {
"baseUrl": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('/') ?>"
};
</script>
```

5- Run commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: In magento 2.3.2 version not found lib/web/tiny_mce/ instead of this my url is lib/web/tiny_mce_4/

vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml path i have changed and run commands also but showing same error

Comment: can you share screen shot of it?

Comment: check belew console.log error:

16:57:16.318 jquery-migrate.js:23 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1
16:57:16.466 /static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
16:57:16.474 require.js:141 Uncaught Error: Script error for: tinymce
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)

Comment: are you in production mode ?

Comment: I have same website in two different -2 environment one is production another is development both place seeing same error

Comment: have you minify js ?

Comment: No i did not minify js